PopScope doesn't work with builder inside MaterialApp
I'm trying to wrap PopScope over child but it can still pop. I used it with go router.
return MaterialApp.router(
      ...
      routerConfig: _router,
      ...
      builder: (context, child) {
        ....
        return PopScope(
          canPop: false,
          child: ...
        );
      },
    );

What's wrong with my code? Can anyone explain it?

FYI: I'd like to disable back button press on physical device, not Navigator.pop(context)

According to the document, the canPop parameter disables back gestures when set to false, Navigator.pop(context) still work, use Navigator.maybePop(context) instead.
